Angular Native Federation - main.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js:2:1)
I am using the new Angular framework Native Federation with Angular version 17.3.2. and native federation version 17.1.8. I have three Angular projects, one is the shell and the others are microfrontend. Each project is a different repository.
When I run the shell I have two issues, one per microtrontend.
main.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js:2:1)

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot.
I need help to know why these errors are reproducing

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
